# How to handle single element array strings before calling split in Groovy?

Tags: string, csv, groovy

I am reading from a CSV file in Groovy like so....

```
inputFile.eachLine { rawLine ->

    def line = rawLine.split(',')

    def name = line[0]
    def occupation = line[1]
}
```

But some values in the CSV have only one entry before the comma like the third example below...

```
   Jim, Salesman
   Michael, Manager
   Creed,
   Pam, Receptionist
```

When it reaches that third entry it gives an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1.

What is the best way to check for this and make it skip such records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow a third-party library as an answer, an excellent way is the following: (The `@Grab` feature makes this trivial to use in scripts.)

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.0')

import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

def inputFile = new File("abc.csv")
def text = inputFile.getText()

def data = parseCsv(text)

data.each { def line ->
    def name = line.getAt(0)
    def occupation = line.getAt(1)

    println "name: ${name} occupation: ${occupation}"
}
```

This handles the use-case without any changes, and the parser is far more robust than most people would want to implement.

Comment: `xlson` library is simple and effective.  To add to Michael Easter, user can use column name(apart from `line.getAt(0)`) , say `line.name` (assuming `name` is header in csv file) to retrieve the value.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you can check the length of the array like this:

```
String[] line = rawLine.split(',');
if(line.length > 1) {
    String name = line[0];
    String occupation = line[1];
    ...
}
```

It should be something similar in groovy.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution is as an example:

```
def s = "S,"
def l = s.tokenize(",")
def x = l[1]?:"No Value"
println x
```

Prints "No Value" in the console

So in your code you can use:

```
inputFile.eachLine { rawLine ->
    def line = rawLine.tokenize(',')
    def name = line[0]
    def occupation = line[1]?:""
}
```